# Plot a course for Cutthroat Supercluster

Tags: technology, politics, wormholes, space-travel

In year 2417 C.E. many decades after the first discovery verified the existence of a primordial wormhole, a join venture between the federation of Onion Spur Alliance and Andromeda-la Empire assembled the finest starship of its time, RMS Titanic Tukalang-ka and  housed a crew of 1500 strong men and women specially handpicked from the parliament to explore the newly discovered Cutthroat Supercluster consists of billions and billions of primordial black holes and wormholes and a small fractions of gravitars in a galaxy far, far away... What could be the political motivation which could help fund such a noble mission which aims to better our knowledge and understanding of the world we live in? This collaboration between two great fractions is suppose to put an end to the conflict that has been going on for almost eternity, both sides agreed to share the treasure hidden deep within the Super Cluster which is responsible for primordial wormhole.

Comment: This is a case where you decide what political motivation, what the conflict, and what the treasure are. Otherwise if's the 25th century, send for Buck Rogers. This is his bailiwick.

Comment: @a4android This is two years before Buck Rogers.

Comment: @Feyre He's only sleeping. Wake him early.

Answer (score 1):

It started with one side having a better theoretical knowledge and the other with somewhat better thrusters. It was originally an unmanned probe that would gather some data and get estimates on what could be found. Then someone on the approval board had a suggestion.....
Now its not a probe, but has one elite pilot to compensate for all the unknowns the shuttle will encounter. But now the other side want someone from there side to go two. Then there is three crew because there needs to be a military captain, that BOTH sides can tolerate, who can lead the pilots. And if there is three, there needs to be a medical officer. Its not a shuttle anymore, its a frigate and we need a full engineering staff to maintain all the systems. May as well add a cafeteria. 
 The hope of getting to the treasure (that no-one is even sure exists) makes the project unstoppable. 
 Then the scientifically illiterate members of parliament start making "Suggestions". Now things get REALLY dirty as things stop being about functionality and start being all about politics. 
 Years later, the exploratory probe is now the most advanced exploration/war/colony ship ever built and its 11th project manager is in jail for sedition. All for the promise of treasure that no-one can confirm but everyone is certain exists. 
See: Pentagon Wars - Bradley Fighting Vehicle Evolution for how it starts and gets worse.

Answer (score 1):

## You answer your own question

> What could be the political motivation which could help fund such **a noble mission which aims to better our knowledge and understanding of the world we live in**?

I have highlighted it for you. That is the motivation. It is so blatantly obvious that you cannot ignore it.

What do you need to make it happen? What tools do you need to bridge the gap between the powers in play?

Well even when caught up in bitter rivalry, sometimes to the point of being at arms against each other, humanity has found it wise to put aside the conflict for altruistic goals. For instance...

- [Warring parties have declared ceasefire to allow vaccination to take place](https://www.unicef.org/newsline/01pr33.htm)
- [Rivalling super-powers have explored space together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%E2%80%93Soyuz_Test_Project)
- [Wildly dissimilar ideologies have reached consensus on foundational ethics](http://www.un.org/en/universal-declaration-human-rights/)

...for the benefit of all humanity.

So even in the harshest of times, **civility and diplomacy** have their places. And this is exactly where you find the tools to make it happen.